# Tango image format YCRCB_420_SP

Tags: java, c++, opencv, google-project-tango

I haven't developed for Tango for quite a while, but recently I updated to the latest version of Tango Java API and I noticed that `TangoImageBuffer` objects now have `format == 17`, which is:

```
public static final int YCRCB_420_SP = 17;
```

As far as I remember, in previous versions it used to be `YV12` rather than `YCRCB_420_SP`.

```
public static final int YV12 = 842094169;
```

I used to apply OpenCV `cvtColor` function to convert it to BGR:

```
cv::Mat imageBgr(720, 1080, CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat image(3 * 720 / 2, 1280, CV_8UC1);
cv::cvtColor(image, imageBgr, cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV12);
```

Is there a way to read `YCRCB_420_SP` using OpenCV? I tried `COLOR_YCrCb2BGR` and similar modes, but they don't work.

Apparently, `COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV12` still works and produces somewhat reasonable result:

[image: YCRCB_420_SP read as NV12]

But it feels like colors are off and everything looks very yellow-ish. Or am I being paranoid?

My question is, what is the right way to read `YCRCB_420_SP` images? Is it correct to apply OpenCV `cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV12`?

**EDIT:**

I tried using NV21 as @fireant suggested, but this one clearly does not work:

[image: NV21]

NV12 was much closer to the original colors. The code is:

```
cv::cvtColor(image, imageBgr, cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21);
```

Comment: I'm stuck on a similar problem... I'm working with the Tango **Unity** SDK, and our callback to get camera data (TangoUnityImageData) still says it gives us YV12 frames.   I am on the caporales release.  But these frames are not working as expected... perhaps it has changed like you show, and is mis-labeled in TangoUnity SDK..

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/tango-enums#class_tango_1_1_tango_enums_1ae177f114ecf6fd14e2f6152005ecfe0eaf4f398ec3ced7faeea573a7546fc3036

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image format should be [YUV NV21](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/cpp_basic_examples/hello_video/src/main/jni/hello_video_app.cc#L269) not NV12. OpenCV can convert an image from [that format to BGR  or RGB](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html).

Just a guess, it seems you're using RGB instead of BGR, the image after NV21 with BGR looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I tried `NV21`, and it does not seem to work either. Please see the new edit.

Comment: Are you sure you want RGB and not BGR? COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21 instead of COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21?

Comment: Well, I think you're right. NV21->BGR looks more natural than NV12->RGB displayed as BGR. Still colors on Tango camera are far away from real :)

Thank you for help!